# Generic class field in enum

Tags: java, generics, java-8

```java
public enum Dictionaries {
    FIRST_DICTIONARY(FirstDictionary.class),
    SECOND_DICTIONARY(SecondDictionary.class);

    private Class<? extends DictionaryModel> clazz;

    private Dictionary(Class<? extends DictionaryModel> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<? extends DictionaryModel> clazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }
}
```

I have this enum. `FirstDictionary` and `SecondDictionary` implements `DictionaryModel`, it's a marker interface for sake of using this solution.

Right now I would love to do this:

`Class<FirstDictionary> clazz = Dictionaries.FIRST_DICTIONARY.clazz();`

It's obviously impossible with this design and I can't think of the way of achieving this. Is there any way to do this? I have access to the whole code, so I can modify everything, including the interface (or even remove it).

I simplified all of this, point is that every dictionary is a database table and I have one common DAO for them (instead of DAO for each dictionary), and now I have to cast the result of every read which I would like to avoid. I know that common DAO is not a good idea (or DAO at all).

`Optional<DictionaryModel> entity = dao.getByValue(Dictionaries.FIRST_DICTIONARY, value);`

I can't seem to a way even for any dynamic casts, in the DAO itself or in `clazz()` method. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

I appreciate any idea, even completely changing the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [explained by Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930518/2711488), `enum` types do not allow this.

The most concise solution allowing you to write something like

```
Class<FirstDictionary> clazz = Dictionaries.FIRST_DICTIONARY.clazz();
```

would be

```
public interface Dictionaries<T extends DictionaryModel> {
    Dictionaries<FirstDictionary>  FIRST_DICTIONARY  = () -> FirstDictionary.class;
    Dictionaries<SecondDictionary> SECOND_DICTIONARY = () -> SecondDictionary.class;

    Class<T> clazz();
}
```

But you may reconcider whether `getByValue` really needs to receive an `enum` constant as argument instead of accepting a `Class<T extends DictionaryModel>` in the first place.

Comment: Both great answers, I'm accepting this one, because after all I used this solution, would gladly accept both.

Comment: Hello, is this possible to do this kind of initialization but with two methods instead of one ? Or should I use an abstract class ?

Comment: @Jessy since lambda expressions only work with functional interfaces, i.e. interfaces with one abstract method, you’d have to use anonymous inner classes for implementing an interface with two methods.

Answer (score 4):

This currently isn't possible with enums. The example that you give is also given in [JEP 301](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301):

```
enum Argument<X> { // declares generic enum
   STRING<String>(String.class), 
   INTEGER<Integer>(Integer.class), ... ;

   Class<X> clazz;

   Argument(Class<X> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }

   Class<X> getClazz() { return clazz; }
}

Class<String> cs = Argument.STRING.getClazz(); //uses sharper typing of enum constant
```

But this is not currently a part of the language

Until that time, you'd have to refactor your code to use classes, for instance:

```
interface DictionaryModel {}
class FirstDictionary implements DictionaryModel {}
class SecondDictionary implements DictionaryModel {}

// Following a model similar to how enums are implemented, but with sharper typing:
abstract class Dictionaries<T extends DictionaryModel> {
    public static final Dictionaries<FirstDictionary> FIRST_DICTIONARY 
        = new Dictionaries<>(FirstDictionary.class) {};
    public static final Dictionaries<SecondDictionary> SECOND_DICTIONARY 
        = new Dictionaries<>(SecondDictionary.class) {};

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    private Dictionaries(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<T> clazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }
}
```

Now you can to this:

```
Class<FirstDictionary> clazz = Dictionaries.FIRST_DICTIONARY.clazz();
```